# apc under php-fpm not caching files

Tags: nginx, apc, fastcgi, php

I currently have apc installed and running under php-fpm. The apc info page reflects user cache entries but the file cache reflects 0 files cached. Other similar threads state that if runnning under FCGI, apc will not share the cache between the worker processes, and recommend using php-fpm. I share the symtoms with these people, however I am already using php-fpm and it is running fine. If anyone has any idea here, would be greatly appriciated. Been stuck on it at work for a couple hours now. I have another box set up where it is working and I believe I followed the same procedure, and both boxes are identical. Not sure where I could have gone wrong. I would be happy to provide more information. Thanks.

Update : When compiling APC with debug, I get file too big errors with every file. This is not the case on the working box. Looking through the source, I found the relevant snippet -

```
 if(APCG(max_file_size) < fileinfo->st_buf.sb.st_size) {
    apc_debug("File is too big %s (%d - %ld) - bailing\n" TSRMLS_CC, filename,t,fileinfo->st_buf.sb.st_size);
    goto cleanup;
 }
```

It has the correct filesize in the fileinfo strut, so I'm imagining that max_file_size is messed up. I'm going to try and track this down. Anyone have any idea? This is working fine on 64 bit Ubuntu outside of EC2, with identical configuration and files.

All the build tests from source are failing and hardcoding that value in doesn't help, it still doesn't cache.

Comment: Do you see cache entries increase if you force FPM to only ever have one worker process?  This will guarantee that you'd hit the same worker on each request.

Comment: Charles - thanks for your reply. I have configured with 1 worker and I have the same issue. I am getting user cache entries but no files are being cached.

Comment: It is also working fine on the dev box with 6 workers, all the configs seem the same for both apc , php-fpm, and nginx.

Comment: Stupid questions: You have `apc.enabled` and `apc.cache_by_default` enabled?  `apc.filters` is empty?  Does changing `apc.enable_cli` do anything?

Comment: Yes to the first three, already tried enable_cli, no difference.

Comment: Charles - If i reinstall apc with debug I get repeated Unknown on line 0 Notice: Unknown: File is too big , bailing in Unknown on line 0, but I don't know if this is related or just something with the debug stuff.

Comment: Ooh, that sounds familiar.  Reduce the size of the shared memory?

Comment: Just tried upping max file size and shm values to absurdly high... still same error trying with debug enabled. how can I reduce the size of shared memory?

Comment: Charles - The 2 servers have the same shared memory shmmax and shsmall values. I'm sure this error is why the files are not caching, I just can't find the error anywhere googling around.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm out of ideas. You might want to edit your error message (and various installed version numbers) into your original question.

Comment: Thanks for your help Charles, appreciated.